# Como comparar dois objetos JSON com os mesmos elementos em Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

Tenho duas Apis que me trazem os dados em JSON. Só que não estou conseguindo fazer a lógica para comparar as duas.

API 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

API 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha lógica é comparar as duas no dado `FlightID` e se for igual me dá o resultado.

```
import requests
import json

def flights():
    url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?'
                       'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
    respo = json.loads(url.text)
    return respo



def flightPlans():
    url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/GetFlightPlans.aspx?'
                       'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
    respo = json.loads(url.text)
    return respo



x = flights()
y = flightPlans()

for i in x:
    if "IFAB" in x[i]['DiplayName']:
        if x[i]['FlightID'] == y[i]['FlightID']:
            print(y[i]['Waypoints'])
```

Está me dando erro.

```
PS C:\Users\Positivo\Desktop\api> & C:/Users/Positivo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Positivo/Desktop/api/models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Positivo/Desktop/api/models.py", line 24, in <module>
    if "IFAB" in x[i]['DiplayName']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
PS C:\Users\Positivo\Desktop\api>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você imprimir o retorno das API's, ou seja, se colocar um `print(url.text)` dentro das funções `flights` e `flightPlans`, vai ver que o retorno delas são [JSON arrays](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

```
[{'AircraftID': 'f11ed126-bce8 etc...
[{'AlternateDestinations': etc...
```

Repare que elas começam com `[`, o que indica que é um [JSON array](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), que o módulo `json` [mapeia para listas do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder). Ou seja, `x` e `y` são listas.

E cada elemento da lista é um dicionário contendo os dados de um vôo. Por exemplo, pegando os primeiros elementos de `x` (removendo alguns dados, para ficar mais curto e claro):

```
[{'AircraftID': 'f11ed126-bce8-46ef-9265-69191c354575', ... 'VerticalSpeed': 3.269327180532855e-06},
{'AircraftID': '230ec095-5e36-4637-ba2f-68831b31e891', ... 'VerticalSpeed': 30.30824089050293},
{'AircraftID': 'bec63a00-a483-4427-a076-0f76dba0ee97', ... 'VerticalSpeed': 16.32938575744629},
... ]
```

Cada elemento da lista é um dicionário (delimitado por `{}`), e os elementos são separados por vírgulas.

Então quando você faz `for i in x`, a cada iteração a variável `i` contém um dos elementos da lista, ou seja, um dos dicionários. Isso quer dizer que não precisa fazer `x[i]['DisplayName']`, basta fazer `i['DisplayName']`, pois `i` já é um dicionário.

Além disso, para cada elemento de `x`, você deve verificar se ele está em `y`, e para isso você precisa percorrer o `y` todas as vezes, já que não parece haver uma garantia de ordem dos dados retornados, então nada garante que um `FlighID` de `x` está na mesma posição em `y`: o primeiro `FlighID` de `x` pode estar em qualquer posição da lista `y` - não necessariamente na primeira - por isso deve-se percorrer toda a lista `y` para cada elemento de `x`:

```
for flight in x:
    for plan in y:
        if flight['FlightID'] == plan['FlightID']:
            print(plan['Waypoints'])
```

Acessando agora, encontrei vários casos (seguem os primeiros, só para ilustrar como ficaria o retorno):

```
['WPT', 'CELAK', 'BUGNE', 'CUSBU', 'KSEA']
['WPT', 'SYDNM', 'SYDSM', 'YSSY', 'MA34L', 'ATRET', 'DEENA', 'D178N', 'TAMMI', 'NOLEM', 'NFTF', 'NIUE', 'D064W', 'MMJC', 'D248H', 'PLAZA', 'MEBIP', 'MMMX']
['WPT', 'LAMBY', 'MCCAL', 'XS99', 'HUDZY', 'ZAPPO', 'GRIEG', 'KERNS', 'SOROY', 'KIAH']
```

---

Não diretamente relacionado, mas as funções que obtém os dados de `x` e `y` são praticamente iguais (só muda a URL), então daria para simplificar um pouco, criando apenas uma função para obter os dados de uma URL qualquer.

E vale também [dar nomes mais significativos](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) para as variáveis `x` e `y` (pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas nomes melhores ajudam na hora de programar):

```
def get_json(url):
    return json.loads(requests.get(url).text)

flights = get_json('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?'
                   'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
plans = get_json('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/GetFlightPlans.aspx?'
                 'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')

for flight in flights:
    for plan in plans:
        if flight['FlightID'] == plan['FlightID']:
            print(plan['Waypoints'])
```

Comment: Boa! Não pensei no detalhe das ordens dos elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi corretamente, a primeira coisa que vc deveria fazer seria ter certeza que as duas retornam o mesmo numero de elementos e que tem as chaves que voce quer comparar, em um teste usando suas proprias funcoes, pude constatar que as duas não tem o mesmo número de itens e a cada chamada retornam numero diferentes, exemplo de uma das chamadas:

```
x = flights()
y = flightPlans()
print('Len de x:', len(x))
print('Len de y:', len(y))

Len de x: 403
Len de y: 5798
```

Sendo assim voce teria que fazer a comparação a partir da que retornar o número menor de elementos (lembrando que o retorno é uma lista de objetos do tipo dict), percorrendo todos os dicionarios da lista de menor número de elementos e fazendo a comparação com o elemento de mesmo index na outra lista, para isso vamos determinar qual lista é menor:

```
 # Se for igual, melhor e tanto faz    
_len = len(x) if len(x)<len(y) else len(y)
```

Agora vamos fazer as comparações:

```
for i in range(_len):
    if x[i]['FlightID']==y[i]['FlightID']:
        print(y[i]['Waypoints'])
```

Nos meus testes não foram econtrado valores iguais.

**Explicando o erro do codigo apresentado na pergunta:**
Quando voce faz `for i in x` a cada iteração vc obtera um dicionário de dentro da lista `x` que será atribuido a `i`, por isso que quando voce tenta fazer `x[i]['FlightID'] == y[i]['FlightID']` é levantado uma exceção com a mensagem de erro:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Ou seja, só é possível fazer referencia a um elemento de uma lista atavés de um indice que seja um integer ou 'fatias' e não um dicionário.

**Observação final:**
Se voce imprimir qualquer elemento da chave FlightID, vai perceber que o valor retornado é o que o nome sugere um ID e do tipo UUID, por exemplo `print(x[0]['FlightID'])` retorna: `abc22393-cea3-4695-8ff1-0deb60f2eb80` então parece pouco provável que voce encontre valores identicos.

Answer (score -1):

Tente trocar seu loop for por

```py
for i in range(len(x)):
    if "IFAB" in x[i]['DiplayName']:
        if x[i]['FlightID'] == y[i]['FlightID']:
            print(y[i]['Waypoints'])
```

Porque no formato em que esta a variável `i` do loop for não é um numero de índice para obter o item do array.

Neste formato acima você consegue fazer um loop na lista de objetos e capturar um a um  e acessar suas propriedade.

Comment: Se `len(x)` for maior que `len(y)` (o que é possivel) vai bugar. :-)

Comment: @Sidon bem apontado realmente esta validacao se faz necessaria antes de execultar o loop como mensionado ```_len = len(x) if len(x)<len(y) else len(y)```